RuntimeError: NCCL Error 3: internal error - please report this issue to the NCCL developers
I am trying to fine-tune Llama-2 for QA, and after coding the QLORA params and training params, while training the model I am facing this "RuntimeError: NCCL Error 3: internal error - please report this issue to the NCCL developers" issue. The code seems to run well on google colab, but it doesnt on my remote-server which has a GPU in it.
from transformers import TrainingArguments

output_dir = "./results"
per_device_train_batch_size = 4
gradient_accumulation_steps = 4
optim = "paged_adamw_32bit"
save_steps = 100
logging_steps = 10
learning_rate = 2e-4
max_grad_norm = 0.3
max_steps = 100
warmup_ratio = 0.03
lr_scheduler_type = "constant"

training_arguments = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir=output_dir,
    per_device_train_batch_size=per_device_train_batch_size,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=gradient_accumulation_steps,
    optim=optim,
    save_steps=save_steps,
    logging_steps=logging_steps,
    learning_rate=learning_rate,
    fp16=True,
    max_grad_norm=max_grad_norm,
    max_steps=max_steps,
    warmup_ratio=warmup_ratio,
    group_by_length=True,
    lr_scheduler_type=lr_scheduler_type,
)

from trl import SFTTrainer

max_seq_length = 512

trainer = SFTTrainer(
    model=model,
    train_dataset=dataset,
    peft_config=peft_config,
    dataset_text_field="text",
    max_seq_length=max_seq_length,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    args=training_arguments,
)

for name, module in trainer.model.named_modules():
    if "norm" in name:
        module = module.to(torch.float32)

trainer.train()

/// here is where im facing the error:
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 1
----> 1 trainer.train()

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/trl/trainer/sft_trainer.py:361, in SFTTrainer.train(self, *args, **kwargs)
    358 if self.neftune_noise_alpha is not None and not self._trainer_supports_neftune:
    359     self.model = self._trl_activate_neftune(self.model)
--> 361 output = super().train(*args, **kwargs)
    363 # After training we make sure to retrieve back the original forward pass method
    364 # for the embedding layer by removing the forward post hook.
    365 if self.neftune_noise_alpha is not None and not self._trainer_supports_neftune:

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1780, in Trainer.train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval, **kwargs)
   1778         hf_hub_utils.enable_progress_bars()
   1779 else:
-> 1780     return inner_training_loop(
   1781         args=args,
   1782         resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,
   1783         trial=trial,
   1784         ignore_keys_for_eval=ignore_keys_for_eval,
   1785     )

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:2118, in Trainer._inner_training_loop(self, batch_size, args, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval)
   2115     self.control = self.callback_handler.on_step_begin(args, self.state, self.control)
   2117 with self.accelerator.accumulate(model):
-> 2118     tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)
   2120 if (
   2121     args.logging_nan_inf_filter
   2122     and not is_torch_xla_available()
   2123     and (torch.isnan(tr_loss_step) or torch.isinf(tr_loss_step))
   2124 ):
   2125     # if loss is nan or inf simply add the average of previous logged losses
   2126     tr_loss += tr_loss / (1 + self.state.global_step - self._globalstep_last_logged)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:3036, in Trainer.training_step(self, model, inputs)
   3033     return loss_mb.reduce_mean().detach().to(self.args.device)
   3035 with self.compute_loss_context_manager():
-> 3036     loss = self.compute_loss(model, inputs)
   3038 if self.args.n_gpu > 1:
   3039     loss = loss.mean()  # mean() to average on multi-gpu parallel training

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:3059, in Trainer.compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs)
   3057 else:
   3058     labels = None
-> 3059 outputs = model(**inputs)
   3060 # Save past state if it exists
   3061 # TODO: this needs to be fixed and made cleaner later.
   3062 if self.args.past_index >= 0:

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1511, in Module._wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1509     return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1510 else:
-> 1511     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1520, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1515 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1516 # this function, and just call forward.
   1517 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1518         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1519         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1520     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1522 try:
   1523     result = None

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py:184, in DataParallel.forward(self, *inputs, **kwargs)
    182 if len(self.device_ids) == 1:
    183     return self.module(*inputs[0], **module_kwargs[0])
--> 184 replicas = self.replicate(self.module, self.device_ids[:len(inputs)])
    185 outputs = self.parallel_apply(replicas, inputs, module_kwargs)
    186 return self.gather(outputs, self.output_device)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py:189, in DataParallel.replicate(self, module, device_ids)
    188 def replicate(self, module: T, device_ids: Sequence[Union[int, torch.device]]) -> List[T]:
--> 189     return replicate(module, device_ids, not torch.is_grad_enabled())

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/replicate.py:110, in replicate(network, devices, detach)
    108 params = list(network.parameters())
    109 param_indices = {param: idx for idx, param in enumerate(params)}
--> 110 param_copies = _broadcast_coalesced_reshape(params, devices, detach)
    112 buffers = list(network.buffers())
    113 buffers_rg: List[torch.Tensor] = []

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/replicate.py:83, in _broadcast_coalesced_reshape(tensors, devices, detach)
     80 else:
     81     # Use the autograd function to broadcast if not detach
     82     if len(tensors) > 0:
---> 83         tensor_copies = Broadcast.apply(devices, *tensors)
     84         return [tensor_copies[i:i + len(tensors)]
     85                 for i in range(0, len(tensor_copies), len(tensors))]
     86     else:

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/autograd/function.py:553, in Function.apply(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    550 if not torch._C._are_functorch_transforms_active():
    551     # See NOTE: [functorch vjp and autograd interaction]
    552     args = _functorch.utils.unwrap_dead_wrappers(args)
--> 553     return super().apply(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
    555 if not is_setup_ctx_defined:
    556     raise RuntimeError(
    557         "In order to use an autograd.Function with functorch transforms "
    558         "(vmap, grad, jvp, jacrev, ...), it must override the setup_context "
    559         "staticmethod. For more details, please see "
    560         "https://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/extending.func.html"
    561     )

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/_functions.py:23, in Broadcast.forward(ctx, target_gpus, *inputs)
     21 ctx.num_inputs = len(inputs)
     22 ctx.input_device = inputs[0].get_device()
---> 23 outputs = comm.broadcast_coalesced(inputs, ctx.target_gpus)
     24 non_differentiables = []
     25 for idx, input_requires_grad in enumerate(ctx.needs_input_grad[1:]):

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/comm.py:57, in broadcast_coalesced(tensors, devices, buffer_size)
     55 devices = [_get_device_index(d) for d in devices]
     56 tensors = [_handle_complex(t) for t in tensors]
---> 57 return torch._C._broadcast_coalesced(tensors, devices, buffer_size)

RuntimeError: NCCL Error 3: internal error - please report this issue to the NCCL developers

